# If statement short cut or improvement?

Tags: php

Is there a way to improve the following block of `if` statements? I was just wondering if anyone can make this code simpler and cleaner.

```
if($key == 'insert'){
    $permission[] = '1';
}else if($key == 'inter-insert'){
    $permission[] = '2';
}else if($key == 'intra-insert'){
    $permission[] = '3';
}else if($key == 'view'){
    $permission[] = '4';
}else if($key == 'inter-view'){
    $permission[] = '5';
}else if($key == 'intra-view'){
    $permission[] = '6';
}else if($key == 'update'){
    $permission[] = '7';
}else if($key == 'inter-update'){
    $permission[] = '8';
}else if($key == 'intra-update'){
    $permission[] = '9';
}else if($key == 'delete'){
    $permission[] = '10';
}else if($key == 'inter-delete'){
    $permission[] = '11';
}else if($key == 'intra-delete'){
    $permission[] = '12';
}
```

Comment: That belongs to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Eh, do switch cases work on strings in php?

Comment: Closevoters: Off topic? Seriously? The second rule of migration is: don't migrate if it's *also* on-topic on the initial site.

Comment: What's wrong with my post of asking a programing question.... what a friendly community

Comment: @bluebill well, I think you got all the answers you need nevertheless.

Comment: YES true thanks for all the friendly help~!!

Comment: It's not offtopic, but this is normally a duplicate ;) Joke aside, I do remember one very similar question at least. Probably it's better to leave a link for those. However, it's already closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [`switch` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) would make your life a bit simpler.

In this simple cases like this however, where it's a simple assignment from one value to another, you could also use an array:

```
$permissions = array(
 "insert" =>       "1", 
 "intra-insert" => "2",
 "inter-insert" => "3",
 // etc.
);

isset($permissions[$key]) && $permission[] = $permissions[$key];
```

Or another variant:

```
$keyExists = array_key_exists($key, $permissions);
if ($keyExists) {
    $permission[] = $permissions[$key];
} else {
    echo "Key not found!"; // or whatever   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$permission[] = $key == 'insert' ? '1' :
                $key == 'inter-insert' ? '2' :
                $key == 'intra-insert' ? '3' : 
                $key == 'view' ? '4' :
                // you get the idea...
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use switch, just like it in C:

```
switch ($i) {
case 0:
    echo "i equals 0";
    break;
case 1:
    echo "i equals 1";
    break;
case 2:
    echo "i equals 2";
    break;
default: break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it also make the code soooo long...

Comment: should have copied example 2 from php.net as the switch must be with strings

Comment: @Yifu Yu change it to `case "0":` and so on.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone Sorry... this is a part of code from php.net... yes we should use "0" instead of 0